# An error occurred while installing .NET (7.0): .NET Acquisition Failed: I

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, tar, .net-framework

Here is the error that keeps popping up with my experience during this problem  (Ubuntu/os) :

> An error occurred while installing .NET (7.0): .NET Acquisition Failed: Installation failed: Error: Command failed: "/home/speed/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime-1.6.0/dist/install scripts/dotnet-install.sh" -InstallDir "/home/speed/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/7.0.8" -Version 7.0.8 -Runtime dotnet
>
> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
> tar: Child returned status 1
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
> dotnet_install: Error: Extraction failed

1. I have tried just about everything that I could personally think of solve this problem and sad to say I still haven't had any luck.

2. Ways I've tried to solve this problem:

   - Uninstalling the Dotnet-Sdk framework and redownloading it multiple times.
   - Manually installing the dependencies/binary
   - Hours of Google
   - Added and removed from home $PATH multiple times
3. Looks like the main problem is when I try to make "Create .Net Project", the terminal will start up loading dots will start to show but it seems like it eventually times out.

Wondering if any one has had this problem or knowing how to solve it?

Here is --Info about the sdk-install:

```
ost:
  Version:      7.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       4b0550942d

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.305 [/home/speed/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.8 [/home/speed/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.8 [/home/speed/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/home/speed/dotnet]
```

Comment: There's step-by-step direcctions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu, though you may have already been using that.

Comment: Your problem is with VS Code, not .NET Core in general. You should investigate why it's attempting to install .NET 7 again, even though it is already installed.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-dotnet-runtime/issues/159) seems relevant